# want my if($object) to evaluate false when count($object) === 0

Tags: php, arrays, object, interface

I made an object that was suposed to represent an array, but with a few methods. So I made it implement the native interfaces: `IteratorAggregate` and `Countable`. That way you can `foreach` and `count` it. So far so good.

But now I want it to evaluate like an array as well. So, if `count($object)` is zero, `if($object)` is suposed to evaluate as `false`. Is there a `Comparable` interface or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php) shows everything that evaluates to false:

- the boolean `FALSE` itself
- the integer `0` (zero)
- the float `0.0` (zero)
- the empty string, and the string `"0"`
- an array with zero elements
- an object with zero member variables (*PHP 4 only*)
- the special type `NULL` (including unset variables)
- SimpleXML objects created from empty tags

As of this list an object will never be considered as `false`. So the only way is to cast the value of `count()` to boolean using `(bool)` if you need to do a strict comparison as pointed out in [Tomi Sebastián Juárez](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15623946/1456376)'s answer.

Comment: Well, there's that. But i'm trying to keep an open mind here. Few weeks ago I didn't know one could `foreach` or `count` an object either. Who knows...

Answer (score 1):

Use [type Juggling](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php).

You can assign  the expected type of your var.

```
$object = count ( $object );
$object = (array) $object;
```

The same way, if you want to assign to your variable some other type, here is list of possible values:

- `(int)`
- `(bool)`
- `(float)`
- `(string)`
- `(array)`
- `(object)`
- `(unset)`
- `(binary)`

Also check this this [Comparable interface](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/comparable).

Comment: haha, would be way better just to implement an `isEmpty` method then. what i'm really trying to do is to make it behave like an array. I have no trouble evaluating it...but thanks for the answer anyway :p

Comment: Oh, you can use (array)

Comment: well, it would certainly behave like an array. but would also stop behaving like my object. haha

Comment: Look again the edited answer. Follow the link of the Comparable interface.

Comment: nice link! apparently it is to be implemented yet...i guess i'll just let the question resting here for a few days, just in case someone comes up with a nice hack (or more info) :p

Comment: No problem, we're here to help.